# Random variable with zero variance: anything else than a Dirac delta?

Tags: random-variables

I've got almost not background in measure theory and just scratched the surface of distribution theory, but I've been manipulating quite a lot of stats and probabilities recently until this question popped in my mind: is there any real variable with zero variance that is not a dirac delta or which measure in not equivalent to $d\mu = \delta_{\langle X\rangle}dX$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $X$ does have moments up to order $2$, then if $\operatorname{Var}X=0$ it must be the case that $X=a$ a.s. (for some constant $a\in\mathbb{R}$).
Indeed, 
$$\operatorname{Var}X= \mathbb{E}\left[(X-\mathbb{E} X)^2\right]$$ and as the r.v. $(X-\mathbb E X))^2$ is non-negative, this implies $(X-\mathbb{E} X)^2=0$ a.s. So $X-\mathbb E X=0$ a.s. Setting $a\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\mathbb E X$, you have $\mathbb{P}_X(\{a\})=1$.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, but please note that a.e. should be a.s..  a.e. is related, but incorrect here.

Comment: Indeed — sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize!